# Calling lua method with binary parameter

Tags: c++, lua, openssl

I am trying to encrypt an input string and passing cipher_text to decrypt it again to the original string.

input string -> encrypt -> cipher text -> decrypt -> original input string

I am calling Lua function (let say encrypt(input)) from C++ code.
I have a callback for this encrypt function in which, using OpenSSL I encrypt the input string and pushed the result into Lua stack.
then I get the pushed string and call Lua function (let say decrypt(ciper_text)).

encEncrypt("abcdef")
encDecrypt("'\x17Q.J\xce\xab\x94\x83c\xd6\x cqD\x94\x86")

But getting below error
:1: hexadecimal digit expected near '"'Q.JΫ▒▒c▒\x '

What I am doing wrong, any pointer/comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a white space after `"\x"` in your string.

```
"\x cq"
```

Get rid of it and make sure you have a valid two digit hexadecimal after `\x`.
Something like "\x0c".

Comment: tried removing white space, now getting error - hexadecimal digit expected near '"Q.JΫ��c�\xcq'

Comment: @atulya Well cq is not a hexadecimal number. you need two digits. so if your value is c write \x0c

Comment: Thanks @Piglet, got it working after replacing space with 0